# Django user account delete and then return redirect and render

Tags: django, django-users

I want to allow a user to delete his account and upon deletion, I want the user to be logged out and see a html page `account_deleted.html` for confirmation.

students/views.py:

```
def delete_account(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    user.delete()

    context = {
        "deleted_msg": "Account has been deleted",
    }
    return render(request, "students/account_deleted.html", context) and redirect("students:logout")
```

For logout, I'm using the built-in LogoutView function. The logout redirect URL in my settings.py is set to my home page.

students/urls.py:

```
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```

In case of an account deletion, how can I make the `delete_account(request)` function return a render and redirect at the same time? Is that even possible?
Thanks!

Comment: why you want to logout user after deleting it make no sence

Comment: i think the simple solution is to add button to the `account_deleted.html` to manual redirect to the login not logout page, or do it by `js`.

Comment: @c.grey because even after deleting the account, the user appears to be logged in. The website obviously crashes when I try to access the user profile.

Comment: `redirect` is just a response with either `301` or `302` code. You can include body in the response, but for proper redirect response it will not be rendered, browser will redirect to the new location instead.

Comment: to prevent crashes in website you need to add login required decorator wherever user is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log the user out before deleting the account by placing `logout(request)` before your `user.delete()` line. You will need to import it with `from django.contrib.auth import logout`.

As Bruno said in his answer, using a redirect instead of `render` is preferable after a POST request, and you should update your view to only respond to POST requests.

If you are having trouble with your website crashing after a user is deleted, make sure you are using the proper access control in all your views, eg by using the `@login_required` decorator or the equivalent mixin on all views that require a user to be logged in. If you do this the user will just be redirected to the login page if he or she is not logged in instead of crashing your site.

Comment: @Shafin M Thanks for accepting my answer but please also have a look at Bruno's answer.

Answer (score 1):

First things firsts: your view should 1/ only accept logged in users and 2/ only accept POST requests (you definitely dont want a GET request to delete anything from your database). Also, this:

```
User.objects.filter(username=request.user)
```

is useless - you *already* have the current user in `request.user` - and potentially dangerous if your auth backend allows for duplicated usernames.

and this:

```
return render(request, "students/account_deleted.html", context) and redirect("students:logout")
```

is of course plain wrong. A view returns one single HTTP response, you can't return two (it wouldn't make any sense), and you can't "and" two responses together (well, you can but the result is certainly not what you expect - read the FineManual about the `and` operator).

The proper solution is to 1/ manually log out the user (cf voodoo-burger's answer), 2/ [use the messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/) to inform the user her accont has been deleted, and 3/ redirect to the home page (you ALWAYS want to redirect after a successful post, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get for the why).